# How is adding these schemes meant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Could someone be able explain how to add prime divisors or their multiplication with the locally finite set $n_{Z} Z$ in $\sum n_{Z} Z$?
[https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BE0#:~:text=A%20Weil%20divisor%20is%20a%20formal%20sum%20D,the%20Weil%20divisor%20associated%20to%20a%20rational%20function](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BE0#:%7E:text=A%20Weil%20divisor%20is%20a%20formal%20sum%20D,the%20Weil%20divisor%20associated%20to%20a%20rational%20function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Weil divisor is a formal sum, i.e. an element of the free abelian group on the prime divisors.

Comment: But how do I multiply a locally finite set with the integral scheme ?

Comment: @dabofskateboarding you can't. in good cases you can consider the intersection of two divisors but the intersection is not a divisor.in general you can only formally add two divisors.